# Change UV Map Image Without UV Map Scaling

Tags: uv

I spent A few hours working on a UV map, then I needed to change the resolution of the texture to be a power of 2. I would like to be able to change this in blender without changing the UV map. How would I do this?

The first image size is 60x123, and the second is 128x128.

Before:
[image: Image of blender before texture changed]

After:
[image: Image of blender after texture changed]

Comment: Do you mean you want to scale the UV map to fit the bottom image?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the UVs in the UV/Image editor, make sure the X and Y cursor location is 0, switch Pivot point to 2D Cursor and scale the UVs using <kbd>S</kbd> button, hit <kbd>X</kbd> to limit the scale on X axis, input 0.5 and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I attempted to do that with "correct" values, but the UV map was not aligned properly.

Comment: Then you will have to scale and move on the X axis manually till it fits the new texture

Comment: Turns out Pixel Snap broke the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Initial situation

[image]

Old Texture is 608x368
New is 1024x1024

Put 2D cursor to your pivot vertice ad set "Scaling pivot" to "pivot"

[image]

scale on X by pressing S and than X. The value from reparametrize the UVMap on this axis comes from the operation Old_X_resolution/New_X_resolution

[image]

In my case 608/1024=0.59

Repeat for Y axis

[image]

---

Suggestion:

in this way you are not increasing the amount of details of your texture in the texturing of the word, as the word DOOM contains the same amout of pixel as before, but in a bigger texture.